# jQuery remote validation not working when two fields having same id

Tags: php, jquery, html, yii

I have an html form like this ..

```
<span id="langBrowser"></span>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td id="sign_up" class="heading"></td>
              <td style="text-align:right">
                 <span class="close_font"><b>Close</b></span>&nbsp;<?php 

              echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/close_icon.png',"",array('id'=>'close_reg_icon','style'=>'title:Advertisement;margin-top:5px;')); ?
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2" id="label1" class="sub_heading"></td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2"><hr/></td></tr>
       <tr>
          <td style="display:none" class="success" colspan="2" align="center">You are successfully registered in MyLokal Network, Please check your email for activating your account.</td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   </table>
             <div id="success_hide">
                 <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="first_name_label_register" style="text-align:right;width:30%" class="label"></td>
            <td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'USR_FirstName',array('name'=>"first_name",'id'=>"first_name",'class' =>'inputtext')); ?></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  id="last_name_label_register" style="text-align:right" class="label"></td>
            <td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'USR_LastName',array('name'=>'last_name','id'=>"last_name",'class'=>'inputtext')); ?></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  id="email_label_register" style="text-align:right" class="label"></td>
            <td><?php echo $form->textField($model1,'UEM_Email',array('name'=>'register_email','id'=>"register_email",'class'=>'inputtext')); ?></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="reenter_email_label_register" style="text-align:right" class="label"></td>
            <td><?php echo $form->textField($model1,'repeat_email',array('name'=>'reenter_email','id'=>"reenter_email",'class'=>'inputtext')); ?></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="new_password_label_register" style="text-align:right" class="label"></td>
            <td><?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'USR_Password',array('name'=>'passwd','id'=>"passwd",'class'=>'inputtext')); ?></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="date_of_birth_label_register" style="text-align:right" class="label"></td>

            <td><?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                                                'model'=>$model,                        
                                                'attribute'=>'USR_Date_Of_Birth',
                                                'options'=>array(
                                                    'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                                                    'changeMonth'=>true,
                                                    'changeYear'=>true,
                                                    'showAnim'=>'fold',
                                                    'yearRange'=> '1910:2020',
                                                    'maxDate'=>'new Date();'
                                                ),
                                                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                                    'id'=>'dob',
                                                    'name'=>'dob',
                                                    'class'=>'inputtext',
                                                    'readonly'=>true,
                                                    'style'=>'width:207px;',
                                                    'language'=>'de'

                                                ),
                                             ));?></td>


        </tr>

        <tr><td class="label"></td><td id="birth_label"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="label"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="label"></td><td id="terms_label">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $pid;?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::Button('Cancel',array('name' => 'cancel_reg_button','id'=>'cancel_reg_button','style'=>'background: #ffffff;color:black')); ?>&nbsp;<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Sign Up',array('id'=>'button','name' => 'button2','style'=>'background: #6495ED;color:white')); ?></td></tr>
                 </table>
           </div>
```

and my jquery form validation and rules are like this..

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ageCheck", function(value, element) { 

                var now=new Date();

                var selected_date_array = jQuery("#dob").val().split("-");

                var selected_date = new Date(selected_date_array[0],selected_date_array[1]-1,selected_date_array[2]);

                return selected_date < now;
    }, "Selected date must be less than current date");
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkemails", function(value, element) { 

    return value.toLowerCase()==jQuery("#register_email").val().toLowerCase();

}, "Please enter the same value as in the email field");

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery('#reenter_email').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
 });

 jQuery('#mlusers-register-form').validate({

        errorClass: "error",
        errorElement: "div",
        rules:{
              reenter_email:{required: true, email: true,checkemails:true},
            passwd:{required: true,minlength:6},
            dob:{required: true,dateISO: true,ageCheck:true},
            first_name:{required:true,firstname: true},
            last_name:{required:true,lastname: true},                   
            register_email:{required: true, email:true,remote:{url:'./index.php?r=user/unique_email_check',async: false}}

        },

        messages:{
                first_name:{required:" First Name field cannot be blank"},
                last_name:{required:" Last Name field cannot be blank"},
                register_email:{required:" Email field cannot be blank",remote:"Email id already registered"},
                reenter_email:{required:" Re-enter Email field cannot be blank"},
                passwd:{required:" New Password field cannot be blank",minlength: "Min length is 6."},
                dob:{required:" Date Of Birth field cannot be blank",dateISO: "Invalid date. Must be formatted yyyy-mm-dd"}

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url:"./index.php?r=mLUsers/sign_up",
                type:"POST",
                success: function(){
                   jQuery("#success_hide").hide();
                   jQuery(".success").show();
                }
            });
       }
  });
});
```

Coming to remote validation for existing email is working fine and everything is okay.

But the problem is when In the registration form replace the id of 'Your Email' field with that of the 'Re-enter Email' field by using Firebug.

The remote validation is showing the error email already registered but the form is submitting. What's wrong with this?

and my php function is

```
public function actionUnique_email_check(){
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit;
        //sleep(10);
        $email=$_GET['register_email'];

        $emails_array=  UserEmails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('UEM_Email'=>$email));

        if(count($emails_array) > 0){

          echo json_encode(false);

        }
        else{

            echo json_encode(true);
        }

    }
```

This is a major bug.

Comment: I recommend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry rohan i don't know how to ask these questions.. please let me know what changes i have to do in this questions ... Thank you..

Comment: You have answered your own problem - jquery only accepts unique ID, and technically speaking for valid HTML IDs have to be unique, too. If IDs occur more than once, only the first instance will be selected. It's less of a major bug, more of an oversight or a design flaw.

Comment: even if i have the same id's for two fields.. jquery validate works with name attribute right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank god..

At last i found the solution for this..

actually in validator add method i added checkemails method... this function taking the value of register email ..

If i change the id of your Email' field with that of the 'Re-enter Email' there is no id register email... Then it returning true...

I changed the checkemails method as

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkemails", function(value, element) { 

    return     value.toLowerCase()==jQuery("input[name='register_email']").val().toLowerCase();

  }, "Please enter the same value as in the email field");
```

then it is working fine..

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use class attribute instead of id